# How to get current language of Siri in Apple Watch

Tags: watchkit, apple-watch, siri, watchos-2, watchos

Please help me to get the current language of Siri in watchOS. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Siri API isn't available yet for app developers. It means you can call Siri, see what Siri is doing or get Siri language in the target Apple Watch.

You can't access Siri features and APIs within apps in either watchOS 1 or watchOS 2.

This is a feature that may be added in watchOS 3, or future builds of watchOS 2.

NOTE: If you need Siri language to translate and optimize your app in the target language, you can use localized strings and this will be done by getting the whole device language (but not the exact Siri language). The whole device language is usually same as Siri, but there isn't anyway to be sure about the exact Siri speaking language.

Comment: Thank you. It's my pleasure.